# How to write a initial script and let it run a command automatically

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, script, apache-httpd, init

As the title saying, I want to start on this.
 
`sudo service (my service name) start`.
 Where do I write this script that can make service initially start? My service is "apache2" and "bluetooth". Otherwise, I currently have a problem on bluetooth keyboard can't get automatically connected after reboot or a wake-up.

Comment: You don't mention what model Pi or OS/version you are running, but Raspbian will automatically start Apache and if you are using a PI3 with built in bluetooth it will also be started automatically on boot.

Comment: Sadly, I own pi-2. Are there any treatment to make it initially start? I have the other service spamassassin I want to make it initially start. Thanks.

Comment: @jefferyear When you install apache via sudo apt-get install it automatically starts at boot.  You need to undo whatever you have done to stop it starting at boot.

Comment: Without knowing what OS and version you are running we can't really answer your question.

Comment: I use Raspbian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I used to schedule on reboot to start my custom monitoring scripts.

Say I have written a whatsapp service that will trigger messages to my whatsapp number when ever I have asked my Raspberry to monitor some activities at home. There are better ways to doing when it comes to services like apache/mongod etc.

cron way of doing -

1. sudo crontab -e (select the editor of your choice like nano/vi etc. This will be a one time option asked by Pi.)
2. @reboot service apache2 restart

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank your response so that I am able to refer to "cron" this schedule tool. I just install cron-apt to make automatically update. But, upgrade this command seems to be done by administrator. I refer some articles they suggest to do manually "apt-get upgrade" this command. I am not clearly  knowing why it is to be manually.

Comment: As far as I know we will be using some stable versions of tools while building a project. Lets say for example when I am building an application I am using a particular version of a server(httpd). My current configurations would work fine at this point. During the subsequent release the tool vendor changes some thing and which would be a part of new release. So when we schedule some auto upgrades this might  take us to trouble. Please accept the the answer you are convinced. Thank you.